# Creating a dictionary given values from a list and dictionary

Tags: python

So, I am given a list

```
a =[[[0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[0, 1]], [[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]]]
```

and a dictionary d.

```
d = {0:2,1:1,2:3,3:4}
```

For the output, I want a dictionary:

```
output = {0:[0,3],1;[1],2:[2,3],3:[0,2]}
```

This output is formed by passing through each sublist of a and checking the number of times each element appears in d.
Let's look at index 0 of a. Now we look at a[0][0]and
a[0][1] and since 0 appears twice in both and 3 appears 4 times (comparing it to d), [0,3] are added to index 0. Similarly, at index 1, 0 appears just once and is not added to the dictionary at index 1.

What I tried so far:

```
def example(a,d):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        count = 0
        for j in range(len(a[i])):
            if j in (a[i][j]):
                count+=1
                if count == d[i]:
                    print(i,j)
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: can you elaborate once again: why do we store `0:[0,3]` ignoring `1` in the 1st pass?

Comment: So at the 0th index of l, 0 appears 2 times in each sublist and 3 appears 4 times which matches our dict d and hence its added to the output. 1 does not appear at index 0 and hence isn't added to the output. For something to be added to the output, it should appear at each element of that index the number of times stated in d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: A version that work

```
from collections import Counter
a = [[[0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[0, 1]],
     [[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]],
     [[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]]]
d = {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 4}
output = {i: [] for i in range(len(a))}
for j, sublist in enumerate(a):
    counts = [Counter(i) for i in sublist]
    for k,v in d.items():
        try:
            if all(counts[i][k] == v for i in range(len(counts))):
                output[j].append(k)
        except: continue
print(output)
```

output:

> {0: [0, 3], 1: [1], 2: [2, 3], 3: [0, 2]}

The try except block is merely for convenience, If you insist you can `if` your way around this by checking if a key is in all counters (which is a requirement for it to be add)

Comment: Hey! I tried this code when a = [[[0, 0, 1,1], [0, 0, 1, 1]], [[0, 1],[0,1]]] and d={0: 2, 1: 2} and the output should be output = {0:[0,1],1:[]} however, that's not the case

Comment: I remarkably understood you wrong yet provided the correct output, I've changed the code (I now understand you better, I think) and it now outputs the correct answer on both cases,I hope it works as expected

Comment: I am sorry I didnt exactly now how to word it but this works perfectly fine thanks!